# Limit the number of posts via wpquery

Tags: wp-query, plugin-wp-pagenavi

We suppose that a category has 1000 posts, we can use the following code to show 10 posts per page and the wp pagenavi would present 100 pages with links of above 1000 posts.

```
<?php query_posts($query_string."&showposts=10&orderby=date&order=ASC") ?>
```

Is there any way that I show only 100 recent posts and hide remaining 900 posts because they may be too old? 
I used the numberpost but it did not work. My code is as follows:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string."&showposts=10&numberposts=100&orderby=date&order=ASC") ?>
<?php 
$mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
$counter = ($mypage * $ppp) - $ppp; 
while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    $counter++; // that pushes the zero based counter up one ?> 
    <span class="num"><?php edit_post_link('♪'); ?><?php echo $counter;?>. </span>
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: *Hiding*? or *Paginating*?

Comment: hiding from the archive so it does not appear in pagination also

Comment: Which type of pagination are you using? Prev/Next buttons. File an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/173324/edit) and show us your function code.

Comment: I use wp pagenavi <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

Comment: Well, in that case I think you should ask this to plugin developer because it's 3rd party plugin. But if you use core function then you can achieve this by modifying function.

Comment: Please add the `$query_string` part also

Comment: If you want to (quoting you) "hide content because it is too old", you should use the date parameters of WP Query and make the correct query for the posts you want to get so you can avoid "hiding content". Anyway, third party plugins are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way limiting the amount of paged queries with what is given by default. You might be able to make use of the filters provided to alter the SQL query.

You also do not want to use `query_posts` at all and most probably you don't even need a custom query. If this is the main query, you would want to make use of [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the the query varaibles before the main query is executed. This way you won't have problems paginating your queries

You can, however, limit the amount of pages shown with [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link). You can simply just set the amount of pages you need.

Example:

```
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries',10 );
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually what you need to do is set `max_num_pages` to `10`.
So before starting your while loop, you will need to set it's value.

```
$wp_query->max_num_pages = 10;
```

Not sure if `$wp_query` is right here, because it's easier to set it in custom `WP_Query` which is recommended to use. Because `query_posts` usually breaks. Read more about it [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

And also, there is no such thing as `showposts` or `numberposts` now, use `posts_per_page` instead.
So here will be your query.

```
<?php query_posts($query_string."&posts_per_page=10&orderby=date&order=ASC"); ?>
```

You can read about all accepted parameters on [`query_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) page in codex.

Comment: I think that `max_num_pages` is a property of WP_Query class that can not be set as query parameter, so your answer won't work. And please, don't send the user to `query_posts` reference: NEVER use `query_posts` in theme and plugins and ALWAYS recommend users to use WP_Query class or get_posts function.